How can I unpack/view contents of modem.img
I have a modem.img file of type - DOS/MBR boot sector, code offset 0x3c+2, OEM-ID "MSDOS5.0", Bytes/sector 4096, sectors/cluster 4, root entries 512, Media descriptor 0xf8, sectors/FAT 3, sectors/track 63, heads 255, sectors 20480 (volumes > 32 MB), serial number 0xbc614e, unlabeled, FAT (16 bit).
How can I unpack/view the contents of this image file?

Based on what you have posted it seems to be a FAT partition, so just mount it on Linux.

I suggest using unblob to extract the contents of the modem.img to your filesystem. You can use unblob as docker container or via command-line. With docker the command to extract could look like this:
docker run --platform=linux/amd64 --rm --pull always -v /path/to/extract-dir/on/host:/data/output -v /path/to/input-dir/on/host:/data/input ghcr.io/onekey-sec/unblob:latest /data/input/path/to/modem.img

